# Populate a list with a specific range of numbers by using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, range

In order to populate a `List<int>` with a range of numbers from **1 to n** I can use:

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
   myList.Add(i);
}
```

Is there any way to achieve the same result by using LINQ inline expressions?

**UPDATE**

Assume I have a method `getMonthName(i)` that given the integer returns the name of the month. Can I populate the list directly with month names somehow by using Enumerable

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Range(1,12).Select(getMonthName);
```

Comment: + .ToList() to evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 39):

You want to use [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx).

```
myList.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, n));
```

Or

```
myList = Enumerable.Range(1, n).ToList();
```

---

If you're asking this kind of question, you might want to look over the methods of [System.Linq.Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx).  That's where all this stuff is kept.  Don't miss `ToLookup`, `Concat` (vs `Union`), and `Repeat`.

Comment: thanks! Assume I have a method getMonthName(i) that given the integer gives the name of the month. Can I populate the list directly with month names somehow by using `Enumerable` ?

Comment: @CiccioMiami generally, when you have a second question - it's best to ask it as a second question.

Answer (score 3):

For the month names you can use `Select()`:

```
var months = Enumerable.Range(1,n).Select(getMonthName);
```