# Populate List<string> with the same value with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I want to populate a `List<string>` with the same string value for a specified number of times.

In straight C# it is:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    myList.Add("myString");
}
```

Is it possible to do this with LINQ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361598/populate-a-list-with-a-specific-range-of-numbers-by-using-linq

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, use [Enumerable.Repeat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx):

```
var myList = Enumerable.Repeat("myString", 50).ToList();
```

or this:

```
var myList = new List<string>(Enumerable.Repeat("myString", 50));
```

If you have an existing list you want to add those elements to, use this:

```
myList.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat("myString", 50));
```

Note that this is not exactly LINQ per se, but it uses the extension methods that was added together with LINQ to support the new syntax. With *just* LINQ (ie. the "from ... select" syntax), it's a bit different, then I would do this:

```
var myList = (from idx in Enumerable.Range(0, 50) select "myString").ToList();
```

However, I wouldn't *actually* do this, I would instead use the methods of `Enumerable`.

Also, if you want to create *different* strings, depending on whether it is the first, second, third, etc. item you're adding, you can use [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) instead:

```
var myList = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(idx => "myString#" + idx).ToList();
```

Will create a list with the strings `myString#0`, `myString#1`, `myString#2`, ...

Comment: @Lasse Very detailed explanation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Whoa, whoa, whoa! Looks like I have a good reason to stop using `Enumerable.Range(0, qty).Select(n => "myString")` now... :)

Answer (score 18):

The best tool for the job is [`Enumerable.Repeat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx):

```
var myList = Enumerable.Repeat("myString", 50).ToList();
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var myList = Enumerable.Repeat("myString", 50).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(i => "myString").ToList()
```